# Workflow to convert and email document

Tags: workflow, pdf

I'm new here and new to sharepoint/Nintex and am looking for some guidance!

I have a work flow on list, which takes user input and puts it into a word document, which then is saved to a library. - this works!

From this library another workflow runs, converting the docx to PDF. using a regex which takes the docx and replaces it with PDF then using the file converter to make a PDF. Up until this point it works, though it is very slow.- is there another service I can call to do this faster? (It's taking 10 mins or longer at the moment).

Once converting the file to PDF, I have a send email notification. Which takes an email address from the list and sends the PDF. How do I attach the PDF in the library to the email?

IF you need to know anything else please let me know

Comment: what sharepoint version you are using?

Comment: 2010 and nintex 2010

Answer (score 0):

The standard MS-Word to PDF Converter that Ships with Nintex Workflow relies on the Word Automation Services (WAS) that ships as part of the commercial version of SharePoint 2010 (it is not present in SharePoint foundation).

According to our developers (they are biased as we develop a competing product) WAS deserves its own place in hell. As you have noticed, it can be painfully slow and it is also quite picky about which documents it can convert successfully.

There are a number of third party PDF Converters that plug in to SharePoint and Nintex Workflow. Have a look at [this product](http://support.muhimbi.com/entries/21239861-How-can-I-use-the-PDF-Converter-in-combination-with-Nintex-workflow-), it does exactly what you need.

As I mentioned earlier, consider me biased as I worked on this product (it is pretty awesome though :-)